# Why do multiple shortcodes on a single wordpress page not working?

Tags: civicontribute, wordpress

I saw that this issue was resolved in version 4.6 (which I am on) but for some reason when I add shortcode for a contribution page followed by another shortcode for a membership signup (to enter their personal info etc), the page reverts to two hyperlinks (says: "find out more") and if I click on them it brings me to separate pages. I want both to display on the same page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You're not doing anything wrong JDM - it's just that Civi itself is unable to do this. The shortcode "teaser" is the next best thing, i.e. a way to show that Civi content exists and offering a way to navigate to the Civi content.